# When Ali was young , he .......................... exercise every day out of his habit. -choose: 1.did not use to. or 2.would not

Tags: past-tense

My English teacher showed me this question, but I could not answer it.

> When Ali was young , he .......................... exercise every day out of his habit.
>
> choose: 1.did not use to. or 2.would not

He told me before that ( would ) is equal to( used to ), but he responded to this question with (did not use to).

what is the right answer and how do differentiate between would and used to????

Comment: "out of his habit" is unnatural English, so this question cannot be answered. Also, "would" is not equal to "use to", so I wouldn't trust that teacher

Comment: The example sentence is odd.  Specifically "out of his habit" is not idiomatic.  Moreover the general sense is unclear.

Comment: The expression is out of habit, not out of his habit.

Answer (score 0):

"Would" has several meanings.  It can be used for past habits. It is also used for the conditional verb phrases. It can also express determination.

I understand meaning of "would not" in this context to mean "was determined not to", or "refused to"

> Katie would not exercise, even though I offered to pay her for every mile she ran.  (= Katie refused to exercise)

"Used to" is only used for past habits, and "didn't use to exercise" is possible.

Unfortunately this sense doesn't fit with "every day". You can say "I used to exercise everyday"  Or you can say "I didn't use to exercise at all". But "I didn't use to exercise every day" is not idiomatic.

Instead you should use simple past

> When Ali was young he didn't exercise every day.

or, with different meaning

> When Ali was young he never exercised.

Comment: Ali  used to exercise every day out of habit. It is a habit.

Comment: yeah, but used like this, it is not idiomatic.  I know why it is there (to hint at the grammar) but still.

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore "out of his habit" being unidiomatic, I think "did not use to" is ok.

The question means Ali exercises now (which is good), but in the past he did not used to do it voluntarily (maybe someone made him exercise, because he was lazy)

So, "used to" can be used both for actions and situations, while "would" is used for actions that kept on happening/failing in the past.

Since "not doing something can be considered as a situation that kept on for some time in the past, rather than being an action", number 1 (did not used to) seems to be the better of the two.